# How to repair a 86 pontiac firebird that has oil in the radiator?

Tags: engine, radiator

I have a 1986 Pontiac firebird 2.8l engine. My ex boyfriend accidentally (or intentionally)poured oil into my radiator without my knowledge and I drove the car until it died (no longer starts) after hearing a knocking sound coming from underneath my hood and the car would not accelerate over 20 mph. How can i fix this problem??

Answer (score 1):

**Possibly a blown head gasket.**
Did the car overheat when you started losing the ability too go over 20? If so the engine may have overheated too much and blown a head gasket (why it wont start). Any other details on the no start would be helpful.

Comment: I believe it did, the car has no thermostat. I purchased one when i had my water pump replaced but the mechanic forgot to put it on and also the fan itself stopped working. Someone had to rig my fan to the battery just to make it come on, and now the car itself is killing any battery that goes in it.

Comment: @LeShawnLSanders Your car really has no temperature gauge of any kind? My '86 Camaro - basically the same thing  as your  Firebird - definitely had one. The only cars I've seen without a temperature  gauge are either 60 years old, or they have one of the multifunction  displays that didn't really come into use until the late  90s.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certain it's the head gasket. Quick way to confirm is to check your oil filler cap, if it has a milky residue, normally caused by coolant and oil mixing.